# Table cursor in Perl

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, cursor, dbi

I want to iterate over a big table that don't fits in the memory.

In Java, I can use a cursor and load the contents as needed and not overflow the memory. How I do the same with Perl?

The database I'm using is PostgreSQL and DBI.

Comment: What database? What perl module? What code?

Comment: @BrianRoach Sorry, I'm new in Perl. PostgreSQL and DBI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a PostgreSQL cursor from PostgreSQL database.

```
my $sql = "SOME QUERY HERE";
$dbh->do("DECLARE csr CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR $sql");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("fetch 100 from csr");
$sth->execute;

while(my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {     
    //... - processing here
    if ($count % 100 == 0){             
        $sth->execute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how is `$count` defined?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a database cursor in PostgreSQL. An example from the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-fetch.html):

```
BEGIN WORK;

-- Set up a cursor:
DECLARE liahona SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM films;

-- Fetch the first 5 rows in the cursor liahona:
FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM liahona;

 code  |          title          | did | date_prod  |   kind   |  len
-------+-------------------------+-----+------------+----------+-------
 BL101 | The Third Man           | 101 | 1949-12-23 | Drama    | 01:44
 BL102 | The African Queen       | 101 | 1951-08-11 | Romantic | 01:43
 JL201 | Une Femme est une Femme | 102 | 1961-03-12 | Romantic | 01:25
 P_301 | Vertigo                 | 103 | 1958-11-14 | Action   | 02:08
 P_302 | Becket                  | 103 | 1964-02-03 | Drama    | 02:28

-- Fetch the previous row:
FETCH PRIOR FROM liahona;

 code  |  title  | did | date_prod  |  kind  |  len
-------+---------+-----+------------+--------+-------
 P_301 | Vertigo | 103 | 1958-11-14 | Action | 02:08

-- Close the cursor and end the transaction:
CLOSE liahona;
COMMIT WORK;
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
my $s = $h->prepare(select ...);
$s->execute;
while(my $row = $fetchrow_arrayref) {
  ; # do something
}
```

Comment: The result of the query go to the memory. If the result is bigger than the memory, there is SWAP and slow.

Comment: Not from a DBI perspective it doesn't. This fetches one row at a time from the DBD. If the DBD chooses to return more than one row at a time that is a different issue and I'd expect something in the DBD or client library it depends on to allow you to modify that behavior.

Comment: libpq itself will always buffer an entire result set into memory: there's no way round it in DBI apart from explicitly using cursors

Answer (score 0):

Look at DBD::Pg [docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#Cursors) for an example.

Use DBI fetchrow_* functions in a while() loop for smaller memory allocation, avoid fetchall_*.

Other database options related to memory usage:

- LongReadLen - maximum length of 'long' type fields (LONG, BLOB, CLOB, MEMO, etc.)
- RowCacheSize (not used in DBD::Pg) -  A hint to the driver indicating the size of the local row cache that the application would like the driver to use for future "SELECT" statements.